# Bootstrap Panels align and organize in the full page view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the below HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
          </div>

        </div>
        </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content Panel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>          

      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test   Test Test 
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>          
      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>          
      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>          
      <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
 </body>
 </div>
```

but there is a gap between each panels

[image: panel gaps]

Above example is only sample. I am planing to use a loop to generate the panels and show news contents on the page could go up to over 100 panels on the page.

My question is how to remove the above gaps ?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap isn't designed to do that. If you notice it will push the next combined elements whose width = 12 col's down past the highest element.

So in your example image you have 4 col-md-3's which equals 12. The farthest right element has the most content, therefor the next element, may it be a col-md-12 or col-md-3 will be pushed lower then that element.

Its hard to build a masonry layout without any jQuery or Javascript help..

Edit -

A solution is possible without the use of jQuery or javascript. By use of Flexbox you can create a 'masonry' style layout.

Take a look at this article that explains more on a [Flexbox](http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox_) masonry layout.

Answer (score 0):

i think its will help you for looping panel in bootstrap,

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <100 ; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">      
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content Panel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel contentPanel content
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
<?php 
$no++;
$x= $no % 3;
if ($x=='0') { ?></div><div class="row" style="">
<?php } }?>
```

I make it 4 column in one row

Answer (score 0):

Read up on css "display:flex" property. You should be able to align all of the panes to the same size using that.

It is best explained here:

http://clearleft.com/thinks/270

Basically, set the parents property style in the css to display:flex and set the flex-warp property to wrap

Then set the height of the panel to be 100% so that it takes the height of the whole container. See the above link to figure out how to change the contents inside the panel to deal with flex.

Comment: Explain your answer.